# How to make spiky hollow ball?

Tags: modeling

How to make spiky hollow ball?

I tried with wire modifier and play with faces but thats not it. I'm looking for more organic holes

[image: I tried with wire modifier and play with faces but thats not it. I'm looking for more organic holes]

How to make this (just sculpting)?

[image: how to make this(just sculpting)]

Answer (score 6):

Enable the addon called *Add Mesh: Extra Objects*, then create a *Mesh > Math Function > Regular Solid*:

[image]

In the *Operator Box* choose *Source > Dodecahedron*:

[image]

Edit the mesh to dissolve all the oblique edges:

[image]

Give your object a *Skin* modifier and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. To give more thickness to the branches, select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]

Apply the *Skin* modifier, select the junction faces, inset with <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

Scale up a bit, extrude the faces along normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>), or, as Gordon Brinkmann recommends, <kbd>i</kbd> to inset then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to scale up:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> if you want to change the thickness:

[image]

Comment: +1 love your solutions! ;) but didn't he write: "just sculpting"? ;)

Comment: Maybe but It's tagged as "modeling", also i'm not sure why he would want to sculpt

Comment: You could also do this only with the inset tool: After the first inset, make a second one to create smaller faces in the desired tip size and before confirming the action, press `Ctrl` to move the tips outwards.

Comment: ...I understood that "just sculpting?" more like "is sculpting the only way or is there some other method?", so I guess the answer is good.

Comment: Yes insetting and scaling is good as well, actually insetting is a kind of extrusion (on the same plane as the selection)

Comment: Insetting with `Ctrl` is actually called _Depth_ in the tool, not scaling ;) And it is not like scaling, as you said insetting is a kind of extrusion and the depth is more like moving outwards in normal direction because you are not scaling the faces outwards by that option (since they are not increasing or decreasing in size), the scale of the faces is determined by the insetting itself.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann OK thanks I didn't know this option, not sure in what context it's better than an extrusion + scale though

Comment: @moonboots I guess that's opinion-based. For extruding and scaling the tips you have to make sure to have the pivot point set to individual origins - or how did you do it? You only say `Alt`+`E`, extrude faces along normals, but that does not scale the tips down like shown in your screenshot. With `I` and `Ctrl`+`I` this works automatically with individual origins even if the _Transform Pivot Point_ is set to _Median_ (what you needed before extruding when you wrote "scale up a bit" I guess?) And you do not even have to switch between different shortcuts. So I prefer it for simplicty ;)

Comment: Ah yes of course, you're right, thanks for the tip